# Visible or hidden dropdown field in the form when a checkbox is yes or no

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

When the checkbox is true or yes, the dropdown should be visible in the form. If not it should be invisible. This should be instantaneous.

I'm using SharePoint Designer. I tried creating workflow but I failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
       <script src="URL to your jQuery-1.3.2.js file" type=text/javascript></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

// Execute the following JavaScript after the page has fully loaded, when it's ".ready"
$(document).ready(function()

{  
//Define which columns to show/hide by default

    $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to hide")').closest('tr').hide();

    $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to hide")').closest('tr').show();

//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection 

    $("select[title='Display Name of Drop Down Column']").change(function()

 {

     if ($("select[title='Display Name of Drop Down Column']").val() == "Drop Down Selection 1")  
{ 

     $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to hide")').closest('tr').hide();

     $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to show")').closest('tr').show();

  } 

      else if($("select[title='Display Name of Drop Down Column']").val() == "Drop Down Selection 2")
{ 

     $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to hide")').closest('tr').hide();

     $('nobr:contains("Display Name of Column to show")').closest('tr').show();

  } 

 });

});

</script>
```

Comment: I tried using this script but i am not able to get any changes..

Comment: Even if you get the JavaScript working, it will not work instantly but with a small delay (which I don't think you want?)

Comment: oh fine....can someone help me by modifing this code using checkbox instead of dropdown

Answer (score 0):

depending on your default value for checkbox, you can add css to your dropdown.
say for e.g. by default checkbox is unchecked and hence your dropdown should be invisible on page load, you can customize form in SPD, and add css to the td to hide it (display:none), and now in js, you can add logic to show hide based on the user selection.